# replacing whole word with .Replace() using \b not working

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string in which I want to replace a whole word. This is what I have:

```
var TheWord = "SomeWord";
TheWord = "\b" + TheWord + "\b";

TheText = TheText.replace(TheWord, "SomeOtherWord");
```

I'm using `"\b"` because I only want to replace `"SomeWord"`, not `"SomeWordDifferent"`. The text looks like this: `var TheHTML = '<div class="SomeWord">';` However, the replacement doesn't take place. What do I need to change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes. Try either of these...

```
TheWord = @"\b" + TheWord + @"\b";
```

or

```
TheWord = "\\b" + TheWord + "\\b";
```

Comment: Unfortunately, neither works. I think the problem is that the word is nested inside javascript. For instance, something like this: var TheHTML = '<div class="SomeWord">';

Comment: You do need to use `Regex.Replace(subject, regex, replacement)`, not `subject.replace(text, replacement)`, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to use Regex. The method for this is

```
string Regex.Replace(string input, string replacment)
```

So I think this is what you want:

```
string text = ...; // text comes from somewhere

string pattern = @"\bSomeWord\b"; // escape \b (word boundary regex anchor), or use verbatim string literal, like here

var regex = new Regex(pattern);

text = regex.Replace(text, "SomeOtherWord");
```

Or simply the static version of `Replace` method as Tim wrote:

```
Regex.Replace(text, pattern, "SomeOtherWord");
```

Comment: Actually, I'm not using Regex, just the C# .Replace() method.